# html file is not showing anything until i close the alert popup

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have just started to learn web development using html css and javascript. but after connecting my file with index.js file, its not showing anything on the page. first it alerts("hello from javascript"), then until i close the alert popup, page content doesnot show
heres my code for html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <title>Document</title>
     <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
     <h1>First Website </h1>
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat similique vitae, aliquam in ipsum explicabo saepe repudiandae quidem recusandae vel dolores beatae iure temporibus aliquid libero adipisci alias obcaecati magni ratione nesciunt impedit mollitia. Tempore nulla porro, deleniti architecto fugit animi ut, inventore asperiores nobis labore cumque soluta. Suscipit, laborum.</p>
     
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possible reason could be your `script` tag, as your `script` tag is placed before the body. The better place to put all of your `script` tags is at the bottom of the `body` tag.

```
<head>
     <title>Document</title> 
</head>
<body>
     
     
     <!-- script tags at the bottom of body -->
     <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dear
You may not have called the correct path to the file (index.js).

second thing it is recommended to place the JavaScript files at the bottom of the body.
like the code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Title Here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Dev. Karam Zomlut</h1>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: my html and js files are in the same folder,  but issue was the second problem you mentioned, place javascript file at bottom, and yeah it worked